# how to check for Notice (8) Undefined index

Tags: php

I know why I am getting this error, and this is because there currenly no ratings for this specific dish, so it is null or empty but I am not sure how to handle it.. I tried this but still the same error came up..

```
     if(empty($rate_dishes[$j]["DishRating"]["dish_id"]))
     {
        echo $this->Form->hidden('dish_id', array('value'=> $this->params['var']));
     }
     else
     {
       echo $this->Form->hidden('dish_id', array('value'=> $rate_dishes[$j]["DishRating"]["dish_id"]));
     }
```

Basically I am providing the dish id if its not provided by the posted array.. Whenever there is a rating for that particular dish it takes the 'else' condition.. but if it does not have a rating.. it gets to the first condition and still shows that error..

```
the URL would be  /special_dishes/rate_dishes/4/?var=4
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't check for empty indices in that case, but rather if the array key exists. This is not really a feature of CakePHP, but rather just a standard PHP method.

The PHP function for this is [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) rather than `empty()`, as the latter expects the key to be there:

```
isset($rate_dishes[$j]["DishRating"]["dish_id"])
```

Also, there's [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), but I believe you're looping through all the data in that post array, so using `isset()` is probably just fine.